# StateT and non-determinism monad: a simple example

Tags: haskell, state, monads, monad-transformers, statet

As part of learning how to work with StateT and the nondeterminism monad, I'd like to write a function which uses these to enumerate the partitions of an integer (while being allowed to reuse integers).  For example, passing an argument of `4` should result in `[[1,1,1,1],[1,1,2],[2,2],[1,3],[4]]` (uniqueness doesn't matter, I'm more concerned with just getting to working code).

(Also, I'm aware that there's a recursive solution for generating partitions as well as dynamic programming and generating function based solutions for counting partitions - the purpose of this exercise is to construct a minimal working example that combines StateT and [].)

Here's my attempt that was designed to work on any input less than or equal to 5:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoImplicitPrelude #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall #-}

import CorePrelude
import Control.Monad.State.Lazy

sumState :: StateT Int [] [Int]
sumState = do
  m <- lift [1..5]
  n <- get <* modify (-m+)
  case compare n 0 of
    LT -> mzero
    EQ -> return [m]
    GT -> fmap (n:) sumState

runner :: Int -> [([Int],Int)]
runner = runStateT sumState
```

I'm using `runStateT` rather than `evalStateT` to help with debugging (it's helpful to see the final state values).  Like I said, I'm not too worried about generating unique partitions since I'd first like to just understand the correct way to use these two monads together.

Loading it in `GHCi` and evaluating `runner 4` results in the following and I'm confused as to why the above code produces this output.

```
[([4,3,2,1,1],-1),([4,3,2,1,2],-2),([4,3,2,1,3],-3),([4,3,2,1,4],-4),([4,3,2,1,5],-5),([4,3,2,1],-1),([4,3,2,2],-2),([4,3,2,3],-3),([4,3,2,4],-4),([4,3,2,5],-5),([4,3,1,1],-1),([4,3,1,2],-2),([4,3,1,3],-3),([4,3,1,4],-4),([4,3,1,5],-5),([4,3,1],-1),([4,3,2],-2),([4,3,3],-3),([4,3,4],-4),([4,3,5],-5),([4,2,1,1],-1),([4,2,1,2],-2),([4,2,1,3],-3),([4,2,1,4],-4),([4,2,1,5],-5),([4,2,1],-1),([4,2,2],-2),([4,2,3],-3),([4,2,4],-4),([4,2,5],-5),([4,1,1],-1),([4,1,2],-2),([4,1,3],-3),([4,1,4],-4),([4,1,5],-5),([4,1],-1),([4,2],-2),([4,3],-3),([4,4],-4),([4,5],-5)]
```

What am I doing wrong?  What's the correct way to combine StateT and [] in order to enumerate partitions?

Comment: My mind is blown by `(-m+)`. What the heck does that even _do_?

Comment: I can't speak to what `(-m+)` is actually doing but I'll explain my intention :)  Let's say we pass an argument of 4 (i.e., `runner 4` into `GHCi`).  The idea is that `modify` will reduce the current state (which, in the first pass, is `4`) by one of the numbers [1..5], which are represented by m.  We then test whether the new state is <0, >0 or ==0.  If <0, we discard the value; if >0, we prepend m to the partition in that particular branch (via `fmap (m:)`) and rinse/repeat, and if ==0, we simply terminate the branch (via `return [m]`) as we've reached the target sum in that branch.

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid It is the partial application of `(+)` to `-m`, naturally. Though it's traditionally spelled `subtract m` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have two little mistakes. The first is here:

```
n <- get <* modify (-m+)
```

This gets the value of `n` before we subtract `m`. You almost certainly want

```
n <- modify (-m+) >> get
```

instead, or

```
modify (-m+)
n <- get
```

if you prefer that spelling. The other is that you're putting the current state in the list instead of the value you're adding in the `GT` branch:

```
GT -> fmap (n:) sumState
```

Change that to

```
GT -> fmap (m:) sumState
```

and you're golden:

```
*Main> runner 4
[([1,1,1,1],0),([1,1,2],0),([1,2,1],0),([1,3],0),([2,1,1],0),([2,2],0),([3,1],0),([4],0)]
```

Comment: Bingo.  (Second one was an admittedly silly mistake on my part...)  Thanks!